# Different between authentication mode and windowsAuthentication tag in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

In IIS 7, if application is configured using below section it is giving 401 error.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

And when below section is added, it is working fine. So, do we need to have both sections in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
 <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
  </security>       
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. you need to turn off anonymous authentication.